# Python Web Server HTML Rendering

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, sockets

I'm building a Python web server and need it to render HTML elements. As of right now the program is implemented via `aj@ubuntu: ./server.py --base=home/website/html/ --port=8080` and then in the web browser, connecting to the URL `http://localhost:8080/index.html`. The only thing that displays on that web page however is `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` which is good since it means I am able to connect to the server. All I need now is the browser to be able to render the contents of the HTML, CSS, and corresponding Javascript components. Any suggestions? I've been scratching my brain trying to figure out how to do this.

I have included my code below:

```
import socket
import sys
if not sys.version_info[:2] == (3,4):
 print("Error: need Python 3.4 to run program")
 sys.exit(1)
else:
 print("Using Python 3.4 to run program")
import argparse

def main():

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Project 1 Web Server for COMP/ECPE 177')
parser.add_argument('--version', help='Show program\'s version number and exit')
parser.add_argument('--base', action='store', help='Base directory containing website', metavar='/path/to/directory')
parser.add_argument('--port', action='store', type=int, help='Port number to listen on', metavar='####')
args = parser.parse_args()
#parser.print_help()
#print(args.port, args.base)


# Create TCP socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Error: could not create socket")
    print("Description: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind to listening port
try:
    host=''  # Bind to all interfaces
    s.bind((host,args.port))
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Error: unable to bind on port %d" % args.port)
    print("Description: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()

# Listen
try:
    backlog=10  # Number of incoming connections that can wait
                # to be accept()'ed before being turned away
    s.listen(backlog)
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Error: unable to listen()")
    print("Description: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()    

print("Listening socket bound to port %d" % args.port)

while 1:
# Accept an incoming request
    try:
        (client_s, client_addr) = s.accept()
        # If successful, we now have TWO sockets
        #  (1) The original listening socket, still active
        #  (2) The new socket connected to the client
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Error: unable to accept()")
        print("Description: " + str(msg))
        sys.exit()

    print("Accepted incoming connection from client")
    print("Client IP, Port = %s" % str(client_addr))

    # Receive data
    try:
        buffer_size=4096
        raw_bytes = client_s.recv(buffer_size)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Error: unable to recv()")
        print("Description: " + str(msg))
        sys.exit()

    string_unicode = raw_bytes.decode('ascii')
    print("Received %d bytes from client" % len(raw_bytes))
    print("Message contents: %s" % string_unicode)

    request = str.split(string_unicode)
    #print(request)
    hcmd = request[0]
    filep = request[1]
    protocol = request[2]
    print(filep)

    if filep == '/':
        filep = '/index.html'

    if hcmd == 'GET':
        dest_file = None
        try:
            try:
                dest_file = open(args.base + filep, 'rb')
            except (OSError, IOError) as msg:
                msg = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Request Not Found\r\n\r\n'
                statcode = 1 #404 request not found
                rb1 = bytes(msg, 'ascii')
                client_s.sendall(rb1)

            message_send = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n'
            statcode = 0 #200 OK
            rb2 = bytes(message_send, 'ascii')
            client_s.sendall(rb2)

            if dest_file is not None:
                datasend = dest_file.read()
                client_s.sendall(datasend)
                dest_file.close()
            print(dest_file)
            print(statcode)

        except socket.error as msg:
            msg2 = "Error: "
            sys.exit()

    else:
        message_send = 'HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented\r\n\r\n'
        statuscode = 2 #501 not implemented
        rb3 = bytes(message_send, 'ascii')
        client_s.sendall(rb3)
    client_s.close()

#Close both sockets
try:
   s.close()
except socket.error as msg:
   print("Error: unable to close() socket")
   print("Description: " + str(msg))
   sys.exit()

print("Sockets closed, now exiting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "home/website/html/index.html" exist in your server? I tried your codes. When accessing an existing file, it works fine. But for serving non-existing files, there's a bug in your codes. The codes for sending file content should be inside the inner-most 'try' block:

```
try:
    dest_file = open(args.base + filep, 'rb')

    #---------Should be put here-----------
    message_send = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n'
    statcode = 0 #200 OK
    rb2 = bytes(message_send, 'ascii')
    client_s.sendall(rb2)

    if dest_file is not None:
        datasend = dest_file.read()
        client_s.sendall(datasend)
        dest_file.close()
    print(dest_file)
    print(statcode)
    #--------------------------------------

except (OSError, IOError) as msg:
    msg = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Request Not Found\r\n\r\n'
    statcode = 1 #404 request not found
    rb1 = bytes(msg, 'ascii')
    client_s.sendall(rb1)
```

Besides, if it's not for learning purpose, using socket to build a web server is really too low level. You have so much extra work to do, e.g. manually compose the common http headers. Try some higher level libraries/frameworks, e.g.

- Built-in http server: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/http.server.html
- The popular web framework Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/

Comment: The location and files do exist, I've tried messing around with a couple other locations on my computer but still the same result. This is a project for class so that is why I'm using the sockets module. We were explicitly told not to use the http.client, http.server, socketserver, or urllib modules for this project.

Comment: What's the output of `print(dest_file)`

Comment: It prints out "/index.html" or whatever file I specify